# C++11 function definitions with auto keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am curious about using auto keyword in C++11.

for function definition,  you must write the return type of function:

```
auto f (int x) -> int { return x + 3; }; //success
auto f (int x)  { return x + 3; }; //fail
```

but in this example the both of them will work:

```
auto f = [](int x) { return x + 3; }; //expect a failure but it works
auto f = [](int x) -> int { return x + 3; }; // this is expected code
```

thanks.

Comment: Simply special rules for lambdas, that will likely be adopted to normal functions / function templates for C++Next, so the second function from the first snippet would compile.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11, a lambda expression can omit its return type if it can deduce the exact one without ambiguity. However, this rule doesn't apply to the regular function.

```
int f() { return 0; } // a legal C++ function

auto f() -> int { return 0; } // a legal C++ function only in C++11

auto f() { return 0; } // an illegal C++ function even if in C++11
```

Comment: Note it has been proposed for the next norm (C++14) and and GCC 4.8 already implement that feature with the option `-std=c++1y`.

Comment: So basically auto is useless for functions (since you have to write the return type either way) right?

Comment: @ErikW Trailing return types are quite useful. Suppose you have `template<class T> class Vector`, and want to implement Vector-skalar multiplcation `multiply(Vector<T> const& v, X x)`. What would be the return type? With trailing return types, this is easy because I can use the parameters `x` and `y`: `template<class T, class X> auto multiply(Vector<T> const& v, X x) -> Vector<decltype(v[0] * x)> {...}.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are required to specify the return type after "->" (as it is in C+11) - what is the point to have "auto" in a function declaration? This is as if to say: "This function can return anything, but actually it is only this type". Uh?
2. Then if you are not required to specify the return type after "->" (as it is in C++14): imagine you don't have the source code of the function, but object file and the header. How do you know what the function returns (the return type)?

So far it seems that "auto" in a function declaration is yet another way to write non-readable code. As if in C++ there are not enough ways to do it already.

While inside function body "auto" is a nice "syntax sugar".

Or am I missing something?

Comment: (1) there needs to be a keyword to make clear you want to write a function declaration. Parsing C++ is already horribly complex to implement. They could have used a new keyword, like "fun", but that would have invalidated existing code which used "fun" as variable or type name. So they recycled an existing keyword.

Comment: (2) you may only omit the type if it can be inferred by the compiler. This implies the compiler needs to see the body of the function, i.e. the function needs to be in the header anyway.

Type inference, `auto` and `decltype` allow you to write things which are near impossible to define otherwise. Not to save you some typing. If you understand what readable code is, then where is the problem? just do it then, write readable code. C++ offers you a lot of choices, but it requires you to be disciplined in picking the right means for your goal